# Mac OS: Is it possible to capture a screenshot of foreign application's window element (NSView)?

Tags: macos, screenshot

I know that taking screenshots of separate windows from another processes is possible on OS X. I would like to know whether application can get content of another application's NSView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this UIElementInspector:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html

If this inspector can detect the element, then it's possible without to much trouble.